# Parse.com iOS issue, PFImageView does not seem to support CopyWithZone

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

i am sending a PFImageView*(Parse.com subclass of UIImageView)* to a new View, where i am adding it as a subview, this ofc leads to the PFImageView getting detached from its previous view, which id like to avoid.

I have to call Copy, and CopyWithZone on the PFImageView, but the class does not seem to support that method, i have also tried the following:

```
UIImage *copiedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[[sender image] CGImage]];
PFImageView *copiedImageView = [[PFImageView alloc] initWithImage:copiedImage];
[segue.destinationViewController setFullSizeImage:copiedImageView];
```

But this leads to an empty PFImageView? Can i add a category to PFImageView and implement the CopyWithZone protocol ? And if so, how would i implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by implementing a category with the following:

```
-(id)copyPFImageView
{
    PFImageView *copy = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
    [copy setFile:[self file]];
    [copy setImage:[self image]];
    return copy;
}
```

Remember that the data in file is quite essential